# How to have multiple ranges for an element as well as a default value in XSD?

Tags: xml, xsd

I am writing an XSD. If I have an element like this, I would like to set `Value`'s default value to an integer. It looks like if I have one range of numbers for the element I can do this but if I have multiple ranges as shown below, I cannot add a default value to `Value`. Is there a way to add a default value to an element that has defines multiple ranges? I think this is not allowed for the type `xs:union` but I'm sure what to do to get both the default and a set of ranges.

```
<xs:element name="Value" default="20">
    <xs:annotation>
        <xs:documentation xml:lang="en">
            Some Random Annotation
        </xs:documentation>
    </xs:annotation>
    <xs:simpleType>
        <xs:union>
            <xs:simpleType>
                <xs:restriction base='xs:integer'>
                    <xs:minInclusive value="20"/>
                    <xs:maxInclusive value="30"/>
                </xs:restriction>
            </xs:simpleType>
            <xs:simpleType>
                <xs:restriction base='xs:integer'>
                    <xs:minInclusive value="40"/>
                    <xs:maxInclusive value="54"/>
                </xs:restriction>
            </xs:simpleType>
        </xs:union>
    </xs:simpleType>
</xs:element>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have a default value for union, as long as it is consistent with the type defined by the union.  In this case, the default value of 20 meets the constraints of the first simple type, and is therefore fine.  If the default value were 200 instead, it would not be allowed.

Answer (score 1):

Defaults are part of the element declaration, not part of the type definition; as long as the value you supply as the default value is within the value space of the type, it's acceptable.  (That is, if you are getting error messages, this is not the cause.)